# Parsing JSON Issue for Android

Tags: android, json

Hello Frnds This is the code which is i am using with Xcode for iPhone and getting the response correctly, But the issue is this while i am using the same url and the same json for android development then i am getting:-

```
{"code":"400","message":"Failed loading JSON. Special characters must not be included in the request. Please check the requested JSON."}
```

I think here is any minor technical issue which i am not finding.
I am new in android development i try it 1000 times from last 15 days and getting frustrate. :-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(:-(
 Can anyone provide me the complete solution with complete code for android. I will be highly obliged you.

The code for iPhone is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.invoicera.com/app/api/check_json_api.php?token=7B92C122473A3D6F54E60D20AC5526D0"];


NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"listInvoice\":{\"client_id\":\"\",\"date_from\":\"\",\"date_to\":\"\",\"invoice_number\":\"\",\"invoice_record_status\":\"\",\"invoice_status\":\"\",\"page\":\"1\",\"per_page_record\":\"20\"}}"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonRequest);

NSData *json_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

NSLog(@"%@",json_data);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: json_data];
NSLog(@"%@",json_data);
// [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [json_data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[jsonRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                      allowLossyConversion:YES]];
```

//  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];

```
NSURLConnection *nsUrlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                  initWithRequest:request 
                                  delegate:self];

// Successful connection.
if (nsUrlConnection) {

   // [self initSpinner];
   // [self spinBegin];

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData=data;
    [data release];
} 
// Unsuccessful connection.
else {

}  
// Clean up
[url release];
[request release];
```

After Writing this code i ma getting the perfect response from the server. But how can i get the same response from the server for android development. Please provide me complete solution with complete code of android.

```
{"@attributes":{"status":"200"},"invoices":{"@attributes":{"page":"1","per_page_record":"20","total_pages":"13","total_records":"246"},"invoice":[{"client":{"client_id":"421","organization":"max styles","address":"H-189,Vasundhara","billing_address":{"street":"H-189,Vasundhara","city":{},"state":{},"zip":........................etc etc etc.
```

This is android Code:

```
public class JSONParser {

    String s1 = "{\"listInvoice\":{\"client_id\":\"\",\"date_from\":\"\",\"date_to\":\"\",\"invoice_number\":\"\",\"invoice_record_status\":\"\",\"invoice_status\":\"\",\"page\":\"1\",\"per_page_record\":\"20\"}}";

    public String payload;

    public JSONParser(String[]array) {
        this.payload = null;
    }

    public void excuteHttpPost() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            // Creating HTTP client
            JSONObject listobj = new JSONObject ();
            JSONObject listInvoice = new JSONObject ();
            listInvoice.put("client_id","");
            listInvoice.put("date_from","");
            listInvoice.put("date_to","");
            listInvoice.put("invoice_number","");
            listInvoice.put("invoice_record_status","");
            listInvoice.put("invoice_status","");
            listInvoice.put("page","1");
            listInvoice.put("per_page_record","10");
            listobj.put("listInvoice", listInvoice);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(ConstantList.invoicelistURL);

            List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data", s1));

            Log.d("Http Response:", postParameters.toString());

            // Build JSON string

            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+NL);
            }
            in.close();
            payload = sb.toString();

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to answer if you posted your Android efforts in stead. That way we could point out the one or two bugs, as opposed to the much larger effor of _writing the code for you_.

Comment: @ Paul-Jan I have update my android code please find full final solution for my code i am very very frustrated :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not use `JSONObject listobj` in your request at all, you add `s1` to post parameters instead. Use this code:

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data", listobj.toString()));
```

Besides, put integer values to JSONObject explicitly: `listInvoice.put("page", 1);` instead of `listInvoice.put("page", "1");`